# Formulae of the Year $2016$

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics

Soon it's the year $2016$. Time to ponder how we can arrange the digits in 2016 to form a valid equation. Use any symbols you like (please explain the less obvious ones). Keep digits in the same order (should this be relaxed?).

Examples:

$$\lfloor e^2\rfloor + 0 - 1! = 6$$
$$\left\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{201}}\right\rfloor = \lceil\sqrt{6}\rceil$$

where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the floor function and $\lceil x\rceil$ the ceiling.

Don't overuse constants (i.e. avoid adding up several $\pi$ and $e$ just to get to some arbitrary value).

**EDIT**: clarification: use each of the digits $2$, $0$, $1$, $6$ in this order only once. Combine digits giving $20$, $201$, $16$, etc as you like (I won't argue whether in a fraction the numerator or denominator comes first :-). Please don't criticize answers that violate this rule, as this clarification came late.

Comment: Like $$\mathbf{e}^{\left( \ln(5+2)+2 \ln(5-2) + 5 \ln(2) \right)}=2016$$ ?

Comment: @ja72 Well, it does use other digits than {0, 1, 2, 6}; but I can blame only myself for not being clear enough in the specification.

Comment: $$~2^0 = 1^6~$$

Comment: @G-man I read the text for the tag "recreational-mathematics" and it said "fun". So yes!

Comment: @G-man, if you think this is off-topic, then the tag (soft-question) should be outlawed in this site! I don't see anything wrong in asking such question under these tags sometimes. By the way, winter-bash is going on. So, enjoy and stop accusing such posts for some days.

Comment: It should be fine to have this types of question here, but the question and answers should be community wiki imo!

Comment: @Kibble Wow! Just wow! And it works for a few years to come :-)

Comment: I'm glad people have learnt a lesson from my golden ratio question. $\pi$ and $e$ ;D

Comment: This question can be continued on reddit. This is too broad for this site. Sorry.

Comment: 7 downvotes already? Would you *please* read the text for the "recreational-mathematics" tag? I refuse to use reddit; its too addictive a time sink.

Comment: Very nice..........+1

Comment: $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z_+}} (n^{-\color{red}2}+\color{red}0)^\color{red}1 = \frac{\pi\pi}{\color{red}6}$$

Comment: @SubhadeepDey you say that like I'm habitually closing posts for no reason. And btw I know Winter bash is going on. Haven't you seen the leaderboard?

Answer (score 18):

An easy one ;-) 
$$(2 + 0 + 1)! = 6$$

Comment: If I allow myself inequalities, how easy is $20 > 16$?

Comment: @jens very, but inequalities are not allowed :-P

Answer (score 13):

$$\color{red}{2}\pi i\left(\oint_{|z-\color{red}{0}|=R}\frac{dz}{z}\right)^{-\color{red}{1}}=\lceil \cos(\color{red}{6})\rceil$$

Comment: How? Could you or someone else explain how this is evaluated / equation reached? You have the unit disc (?)

Comment: The integral is taken over $|z|=R$ counterclockwise. It is a circle around $0$ with radius $R$.

Comment: I see. However why does R not have to be a certain number, what is with the 2*pi*i ?

Comment: $R$ is arbitrary, the integral is equal to $2\pi i$, see [the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem#Discussion)

Answer (score 10):

Another easy one) $$\Large(\color{red}{ 2}!)^{\color{blue}{\Large {2}}}+(\Large \color{red}{0}!)^{\color{blue}{\Large{0}}}+(\color{red}{1}!)^{\color{blue}{\Large{1}}}=\color{red }{\Large 6}$$

Comment: Very Nice! +1 :)

Comment: This is perhaps the most elegant. May be you can write RHS as sixth root of six raised to six to put it in the same form as LHS.

Comment: @Sailesh: thanks for suggestion but OP asked to arrange the digits $2, 0, 1, 6$ in the same order as in $\Large 2016$ so if it is $(6^{\large 1/6})^{\Large 6}$ then isn't it complex more than writing simply $6$?

Comment: What I meant is $(\sqrt[6]{6})^6$  Now you are preserving order and you can probably render this in the same colorful way so that the equation looks balanced. Every number gets a hat (power).

Comment: That is a point. So it should look like $$\Large(\color{red}{ 2}!)^{\color{blue}{\Large {2}}}+(\Large \color{red}{0}!)^{\color{blue}{\Large{0}}}+(\color{red}{1}!)^{\Large\color{blue}{{1}}}= \Large(\sqrt[\Large \color{red}{6}]{\color{red }{ 6}})^{\Large \color{blue}{6}}$$

Answer (score 7):

A simple one: $$2\times 0 = \sin\left(1 \times 6 \times \pi \right) $$

Comment: Ok, but the digits are *not quite* in the same order.

Comment: @Jens, feel free to do edits. Clearer view will be much appreciated.

Comment: $e$ and $\pi$ are both numbers

Comment: @Ataulfo But they are not digits. Creative rule interpretation allowed for fun...

Comment: @Jens : is it better like this?

Comment: @Tryss Perfect -- for quite some years to come!

Answer (score 5):

Arithmetic's fundamental theorem implies $$2016=2^{5}\cdot3^{2}\cdot 7$$

**Edit**:

According to Dan Brumleve
$$2016=2^{0-1+6}\cdot\left(2^{0+1\cdot6}-2^{0}\cdot1^{6}\right)$$

Comment: $= 21 \cdot 16 \cdot 6$

Comment: ...which does use some digits not in {2, 0, 1, 6}...

Comment: Which makes of $2016=2^5(2^6-1)$ a pernicious number, but sadly not a perfect number.

Comment: http://www.numberempire.com/2016

Comment: @DanBrumleve, you mean $2^{6-1}\cdot(2^6-1)$

Comment: Hehehe, $2^{0-1+6}\cdot(2^{0+1\cdot6}-2^0\cdot1^6)$